# How can I get projected coordinates of vertex on screen

Tags: directx, matrix, directxmath

I want to check picking for faces and for that I need projected X Y coordinates of my vertexes in -1 to 1 range:
For that I multiply my vertex array with matrices and then get projected triangle coordinates from it and check if mouse is inside of that triangle ,but something goes wrong:
Here is my code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m_vertexCount; ++i)
{
    D3DXVec4Transform(&m_Pverts1[i], &m_Pverts[i], &worldmatrix);
    D3DXVec4Transform(&m_Pverts1[i], &m_Pverts[i], &viewmatrix);
    D3DXVec4Transform(&m_Pverts1[i], &m_Pverts[i], &projectionmatrix);
}
z = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < m_faceCount; ++i)
{
    x1 = m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].x / m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].w;
    y1 = m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].y / m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].w;
    z1 = m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].z / m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].w; ++z;
    x2 = m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].x / m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].w;
    y2 = m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].y / m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].w;
    z2 = m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].z / m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].w; ++z;
    x3 = m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].x / m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].w;
    y3 = m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].y / m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].w;
    z3 = m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].z / m_Pverts1[m_verts[z].x - 1].w; ++z;

    //code .. //
}
```

Where  `m_Pverts` is array of vertexes  `m_Pverts1` is empty array for transformed vertexes and  `m_verts[].x` is array of vertex indexes: 
`x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z3,x3,y3,z3` must be X Y  projected coordinates of triangle and Z depth:
Other code is checked and works right:

What I am doing wrong ??

Comment: Elaborate on what values you get from the transform? Note that they will be in NDC. Note that if you want something that projects to `w=1` for you, there's `D3DXVec3TransformCoord`. There are also `-Array` functions to avoid your loops.

Comment: Have you looked at ``D3DXVec3Project``? BTW, D3DXMath is deprecated. See [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the solution of my problem: Instead of using `worldmatrix` `viewmatrix` and `projectionmatrix`
i must use `wvpwatrix` which is multiplication of that three matrices

```
D3DXMATRIX wvp;

wvp = worldmatrix*viewmatrix*projectionmatrix;

for (int i = 0; i < m_vertexCount; ++i)
{
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&m_Pverts1[i], &m_Pverts[i], &wvp);
}
```

But I dont know why is it working??

Comment: It's working because matrix multiplication doesn't follow algebraic multiplication laws. So `MVP * v` isn't the same as `P * (V * (M * v))`